# How to generate HTML tags from Kotlin?

Tags: javascript, html, kotlin, kotlinx-html

I would like to generate HTML from Kotlin (running in the browser). I tried the [Kotlinx library](https://github.com/kotlinx/kotlinx) but [it doesn't support callbacks](https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.html/wiki/Events), such as:

```
div {
    onclick = { event ->
        window.alert("Kotlin!")
    }
}
```

Are there other similar libraries? Maybe something similar to [Clojure's Hickup](https://github.com/weavejester/hiccup) or [Groovy's MarkupBuilder](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/api/groovy/xml/MarkupBuilder.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Kotlinx library](https://github.com/kotlinx/kotlinx) does support callbacks. The code example in its [Events Page](https://github.com/kotlin/kotlinx.html/wiki/Events) is wrong. Just include `kotlinx.html.js.*` and use the event names ending with `Function`:

```
div {
    onClickFunction = { event ->
        window.alert("Kotlin!")
    }
}
```

To make things more difficult, the name `onClick` does exist, but it takes a string: `onClick = "alert('Kotlin!')"`

Comment: I think they've updated the doc on that events page since this answer was posted.